# Load a Swagger API Url parameter dynamically in Spring Boot Project java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, openapi

I have a requirement where I have to load a Swagger api url parameter dynamically i.e. at a time when the project compiles. It is a Spring Boot Project. So, for example, if there is something like this :-

[image: Originally you have to enter the petId here]

This api should look like **"/pet/1"** at the time when I run the swaggerUi. I understand that we have to provide the data/file containing the **"petId"** within the project itself, so that the value of the petId is fetched at compile time only. I just don't have an idea where and how to do this in a Spring Boot Java Project where these Swagger Apis are created via REST annotations (Something like as shown below) with Swagger enabled :-
**@RequestMapping(value = "/pet/{petId}", consumes = {"text/plain" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)**
. To sum it up once again - When I run the Swagger UI for my project, the above given api should look like **"/pet/1"** (petId = 1) and not **"/pet/{petId}"**. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @ApiParam annotation like in the following example:

```
    @GetMapping(BASE_URL_USERS + "/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "getUserById() - Retrieves a user by ID",
            authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "basicAuth")}
    )
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Invalid credentials"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User not found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")
    })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    UserDTO getUserByIdUsingGET(
            @ApiParam(value = "ProcessID", required=false) @RequestHeader(value="processID", required=false) String processID,
            @ApiParam(value = "User ID",required=true) @PathVariable("id") Long id
    );
```

And than you get an input field where you can provide your actual parameter.
[image]

Comment: I have this field already to provide userId value (in your example). What I want is that when I hit the SwaggerUI, the api (currently visible as **"/user/{id}"** in above image provided by you) should be visible as **"/user/1"** i.e., the **id** should be dynamically loaded/appended while starting the project.